# Do we need a separate tag for Dwarf Fortress adventure mode?

Tags: discussion, tags, dwarf-fortress

Do we need a separate tag for Dwarf Fortress adventure mode?  Obviously, it's pretty different play experience with different questions than fortress mode.

The tag [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) already exists, but isn't used.  Should I go slap it on all the applicable questions?

Answer (score 6):

**Will it help?**

Seems like it. Several questions already carefully specify the difference, which seems kind of the point of tags.

**Will it hurt?**

I don't see how. You can interesting/uninteresting "dwarf-fortress*".

Unless anyone has different answers to those questions, the balance of help to hurt seems great. Do it.

Comment: Should it replace the existing tag?

Comment: @C.Ross Is the adventure mode no longer dwarf fortress enough to not need the dwarf fortress tag?

Comment: @Grace I think it should keep the original tag.  But that begs the question, do we need a fortress mode tag?

Comment: @C.Ross (made up example with possibly other problems but...) Would we need a "StarCraft2-Melee" tag because of having a "StarCraft2-[InsertMod]" tag? Is one mode clearly the default?

Comment: It's like having a [planets] tag as well as an [earth] tag. The two are clearly related, but the scope of the tags themselves vary greatly. So I would say the tag is a valid one.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

My understanding is that Adventure Mode shares a number of world features with Fortress Mode (item properties, monsters, stats on individual dwarves), but the core gameplay is extremely different.  Questions that deal with Adventure Mode should have the *dwarf-fortress-adventure* tag.

Now, in my experience, when people simply say "Dwarf Fortress", with no further qualifiers, they tend to be talking about Fortress Mode.  I don't have numbers to back it up, but I get the feeling that Fortress Mode is much more popular than adventure mode.  Because of this, I would advocate only the *dwarf-fortress* tag be used for Fortress Mode questions, and *both* tags be used for Adventure Mode.  I don't feel like a third tag adds much value.

Comment: Given that people tend to need the "This is Adventure Mode" qualifier but not an equivalent one for Fortress Mode, I'm inclined to agree with this standpoint.