# Revisiting the Dwarf Fortress tags

Tags: discussion, tags

A few years ago, we had this question: [Do we need a separate tag for Dwarf Fortress adventure mode?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/do-we-need-a-separate-tag-for-dwarf-fortress-adventure-mode)

Since then, we've made a number of changes to how we handle tags, especially in the area of organization for platforms.

I brought this up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8600019#8600019), and have gained acceptance for my modification there.  I'm bringing it to the attention of the community for their input and opinion.

Dwarf Fortress has two different modes of gameplay: Fortress mode, and Adventure mode.  These two game types are different enough that they could, by rights, be two different games.  They're encompassed in the same game, though, so currently, [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) tag is being used as an "expansion" type of tag, to denote the difference.

What I propose is to treat them as two separate games:

- Use [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) only for questions that are about the Adventure mode.
- Use [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress) for Fortress mode, and other questions related to world generation, monsters, items, etc.
- In the event a question relates to both modes, use both tags, otherwise use only one of them.

This way, the game tags are separate entities, with the odd amount of overlap, and less ambiguity as to what the question relates to.

Comment: Similar to how we don't have a "League of Legends" and a "League of Legends: Dominion" tag, I think the need for two tags has passed. All hail `Dwarf-Fortress`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with using both tags?

Comment: I disagree. The two game modes are fundamentally different. An issue concerning one game mode is highly unlikely to affect the other.

Comment: @SaintWacko Not *fundamentally*. All the mechanics are the same, the primary difference is controlling 1 unit or ~200.

Comment: @RavenDreamer But isn't that what we're concerned about here? I could understand that objection on GameDev, but on Arqade, shouldn't we focus on how the player interacts with the game?

Comment: @SaintWacko Which brings me back to the `League of Legends` example. 90% of the content is going to be identical in either mode (iron vs. bronze, etc), and since the ongoing dev plans for the game involve adding more dwarf-mode stuff into adventure mode (digging and building), they are going to get *more* similar as time goes on.

Comment: @RavenDreamer My initial idea was to just dump the adventure tag completely.  If they are going to become even more similar, then I don't think we need that tag at all.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Perhaps this should be revisited in the future, then. I just looked through the Dwarf Fortress questions, and none of the [tag:dwarf-fortress-adventure] questions apply to [tag:dwarf-fortress], and very few [tag:dwarf-fortress] questions would be helpful in [tag:dwarf-fortress-adventure].

Comment: So, a relevant question - why not add a dwarf-fortress-dwarf tag? Or df-dwarf and df-adventure. They're still the same released game,  so I feel like they should share at least one tag. What about modding questions? If I'm asking about material tags for a creature I'm making, that applies equally to fortress and adventure mode, so why should it be excluded from sharing a tag with adventure mode questions?